# It seems the main clause is absent in this complex sentence. Why is it correct?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

I saw this complex sentence in the CGEL Quirk et al.

> What surprises me is that they are fond of snakes and lizards.

In this sentence, the subject is the wh-clause and the predicative is that-clause.
Both of them are dependent clauses(subordinate clauses). why is this sentence without a main clause (independent clause) still correct?

Remark:  BillJ's interpretation is correct. Here is a link of convincing evidence.

Nordquist, Richard. "Free (Nominal) Relative Clause." ThoughtCo, Aug. 27, 2020, thoughtco.com/free-nominal-relative-clause-1690808.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [*What surprises me*] *is that they are fond of snakes and lizards.*

The main clause is the whole sentence in a 'fused' relative construction.

The subject "what surprises me", is not a clause but a noun phrase in which the single word "what" combines, or 'fuses', the functions of head of the NP and relativised element. It has a meaning equivalent to the non-fused *The thing that surprises me is that they are fond of snakes and lizards.*

The declarative content clause *that they are fond of snakes and lizards* is functioning as complement of the verb "is".

Comment: Here arises another problem. In the CGEL Quirk et al, 15.8 / Page 1057,   “ what surprises me” is actually a nominal relative clause and " what" functions as the subject.  There are many examples similar to this structure.  I cite another two from CGEL, " What happened upset him" ,  " What were left behind were five empty bottles. "

Comment: It is true that " What " in the norminal relative clause can be paraphrased into " the thing/s that" . For example,  " (The things that) were left behind were five empty bottles. "  In my orginal example, " what surprises me" is not a noun phrase, but a special clause with similar function as the NP.

Comment: @user421993 That was Quirk et al's not very transparent term for Huddleston & Pullum's term 'fused relative'.

Comment: Undoubtedly,  " What surprises me"  functions as the subject of the overall sentence and " that they are fond of snakes and lizards" as the predication.  As the subject and predication are  two subordinate clauses, where is the main clause?

Comment: @user421993 I've already explained that it my answer: The subject is **not** a clause but an NP.  Read it again. There are several reasons why it's an NP: for example, like ordinary NPs, fused relatives do not occur in the extraposition construction. Here, they differ from clauses: compare “What she suggests is unreasonable”, but not *“It is unreasonable what she suggests”.

Comment: Further evidence comes from subject-verb agreement: Compare (a) "What money she has is in the bank". (b) "What books she has are in the attic". The verbs here agree with the fused relatives in subject position. The crucial point is that the "are" in (b) shows that "what books" is plural, like the uncontroversial NP "all the books that she has". Clauses functioning as subject, by contrast, always belong to the default 3rd person singular category: "That she has so many friends **is** rather surprising"

Comment: *It's unreasonable, what you're asking!*

Answer (score 17):

The main clause is the one headed by the verb "is", so the bracketing is:

> (What surprises me) is (that they are fond of snakes and lizards).

Both the subject and its complement are content clauses, but the main clause is a simple SVC structure.

Comment: Sorry to disagree, but the expression "what surprises me" is not a clause but an NP in a fused relative construction where head of the NP and the relativised element are combined, or fused, into the single word "what", which means "that which".

Comment: @BillJ can't "what surprises me" be considered a relative clause?

Comment: @theonlygusti No because it's actually a noun phrase in a fused relative construction. In fused relatives the head of an NP fuses with the relativised element in a relative clause instead of being expressed separately as in a simpler construction. In the OP's example, "what" is thus head of the NP and subject of "surprises" in the relative clause, giving a meaning like that of the non-fused "That which surprises me is that they are fond of snakes and lizards".

Comment: @BillJ, Yes, it is true that " what surprises me" can be rephrased into " that which surprises me" . Apparently , it is a clause, not a NP.  Also obviously, the predication is a clause ( declarative content clause).

Comment: I also disagree with Mr. James K.  The main clause is not a simple SVC; at least, the subject is quite a complicated construction.  I just found more information on Noun Phrases from British Council, which have a large range of functions , especially when they have multiple postmodifiers.

Answer (score -1):

The overall sentence structure is called a "predicate nominative" because the verb of the main clause is "is". Thus, this structure makes the predicate a restatement of the subject. For ex: "Biden is the President."

"What surprises me" is an independent noun clause whose subject is the relative pronoun, "what", and this entire noun clause is the subject of the sentence. The antecedent of "what" is stated later. Normally, a pronoun's antecedent precedes the pronoun itself. The antecedent of "what" is "that they are fond of snakes and lizards".

"Is" is the verb of the main clause.

"That they are fond of snakes and lizards" is an independent noun clause and the predicate of the main clause, *as well as* the antecedent of "what". "That" is a subordinating conjunction and introduces the second noun clause. "They" is the subject of this second noun clause. "Are" is the primary verb of this 2nd clause. "Fond" is an adjective that modifies "they" making the 2nd clause's structure a predicate adjective. "Of" is a preposition. "Snakes and lizards" is the (compound) object of the prepositional phrase, "of snakes and lizards" which all together is an adverb that modifies "fond".

This overall sentence structure is not good. This sentence can more simply be written, with the exact same meaning, as:

"*That they are fond of snakes and lizards surprises me.*"

Comment: Your assessment that the sentence structure is not good is subjective, of course. Your suggested rewrite has a very different focus, and reads quite awkwardly.

Comment: If I were to rewrite, I'd go for "I'm surprised that they are fond of snakes and lizards", but this does change the focus of the sentence, so there may be reasons for the "what surprises me..."

Comment: @JamesK yes, that's a much better rewrite. "It surprises me that ..." would work too IMO.

Comment: -1 for a wrong analysis. "What surprises me" is not a clause but an NP in a fused relative construction where the head of the NP and the relativised element are combined, or fused, into the single word "what" meaning "that which".

Comment: -1 for claiming that your rewrite has the exact same meaning.

Comment: Further, the expression "that they are fond of snakes and lizards" is not an independent clause, but a subordinate (dependent) clause, as evident by the presence of the subordinating conjunction "that". Sorry to tell you that there are also other errors in your analysis.

Comment: "What surprises me ..." instead if "I am surprised by ..."  emphases the "what", suggesting that there might be other reasons for surprise, or that surprise itself is somehow unexpected. None of the other rewrites captures this. Let the author speak in their own words please.

Comment: "What surprises me is..." is very idiomatic, it sounds fine to me. I think it means the same thing as "It surprises me that...", but I feel like it emphasizes the surprise more.

Comment: @Barmar If anything, it emphasizes the surprise less--by topicalizing it, it treats it as a given that there's something surprising, then clarifies what exactly that is.

Comment: @UnrelatedString I think it depends on the context, i.e. whether the audience already knows you're surprised, then it explains why.

Comment: A "fused relative constructor" is something new to my 30+ years of English. I've experience with teaching English grammar to non-native speakers and just tried to deconstruct the sentence by talking about relative pronouns / sentence structure in a manner that would be useful to the learner rather than pedantic. I'm a new user of this forum and don't understand its purpose. Rest assured, I won't participate in the English Language Learner forum again. I apologize. My mistake. But I will participate in other forums!

Comment: @cognacguy, Sorry to hear that. It is understandable that in some aspects  British English somehow differs from American English.  For me,  as an English learner , I would give respect to both, not just to language itself, but also to people in these two countries.